# Group by in java 8 with value is as custom Map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is there any other way to refactor below code in single line in java 8. To get final output map I am performing two phase operation.

```
class Pair<X, Y> {

      public X first;
      public Y second;
      public Pair(X first, Y second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
      }
     //.... other stuff
}

class InvHistory{
  
    private Integer sysId;
    private Integer sourceId;  
    public InvHistory(Integer sysId, Integer sourceId) {         
        this.sysId = sysId;
        this.sourceId = sourceId;
    }
    //... other stuff   
} 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<InvHistory> invHisLst=Arrays.asList(new InvHistory(1,101),new InvHistory(2,102),new InvHistory(3,102));
        
    Map<Integer, List<InvHistory>> grpMap=invHisLst.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(InvHistory::getSourceId));
        
    System.out.println("Group Map:"+grpMap);
        
    Map<Integer,Pair<Boolean,List<InvHistory>>> newMap=new HashMap<>();
    
    grpMap.forEach((key,value)->{
            Pair<Boolean,List<InvHistory>> accociatedValue=new Pair<>(Boolean.TRUE,value);
            newMap.put(key, accociatedValue);
    });
    System.out.println(newMap);
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any special purpose you want it all inlined?

Answer (score 1):

You're still going to need to `backreference` the list you made to accommodate duplicate source ids.  Once you build the first map, simply stream the entrySet and build the second.  Here is how that would be done.

```
Map<Integer, Pair<Boolean, List<InvHistory>>> grpMap =
        invHistLst.stream()
                .collect(Collectors
                        .groupingBy(InvHistory::getSourceId))
                .entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,
                        e -> new Pair<>(Boolean.TRUE,
                                e.getValue())));
```

But all this is doing is combining what you already have.  I would recommend the following approach.

```
Map<Integer, Pair<Boolean, List<InvHistory>>> map =
        new HashMap<>();
```

- Now iterate thru your history list.
- if the sourceId is not present, add it and create the pair entry with the boolean and an empty list.
- this also returns the just added `Pair` so you can use a `getter` to retrieve the associated `list` add the inventory item.
- if the sourceID is present, the existing pair is returned and you can add it just as before.

```
for (InvHistory h : invHistLst) {
    map.compute(h.getSourceId(),
            (id, pair) -> pair == null ? new Pair<>(
                    Boolean.TRUE, new ArrayList<>()) : pair)
            .getSecond().add(h);
}

map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

With the appropriate toString methods, this is the result for both methods.

```
SourceId = 101, Pair = true [{sysID = 1, sourceId = 101}]
SourceId = 102, Pair = true [{sysID = 2, sourceId = 102}, {sysID = 3, sourceId =
 102}]
```

And as I stated, this requires you to access the `second` value from the Pair object.  Check out [Map.compute](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#compute(K,java.util.function.BiFunction)) for more about the method.